# Can I create a publisher action in for user object

Tags: publisher

Is it possible to create an object specific publisher  action for user object?

If I go to create an action under Customise --> User Button and Links page says create Buttons, Links, and Actions on the head but no option is avaliable for action is there any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  According to the [Publisher Actions Overview in Salesforce Help](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm) User is not supported.

> **Supported Objects** 
>   **You can create object-specific actions on these objects:**
>   Account 
>   Campaign 
>   Case 
>   Contact 
>   Custom objects 
>   Lead 
>   Opportunity 
>   **You can create global actions that let users create these kinds of
>   records:**
>   Account
>   Campaign
>   Case 
>   Contact 
>   Contract 
>   Custom objects 
>  
>   Event (without invitees) 
>   Lead 
>   Opportunity 
>   Task

Comment: @ShebinMathew If you believe this is the correct answer, please mark it as such by clicking the checkmark and giving Peter some extra rep for helping you out! It is what helps drive our community. Thanks!

Comment: Done !! it was absolutely usefull